# Appium Desktop won't open for Ionic App

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile-automation

I am currently trying to automate an ionic app using Appium and Python. I have the `Appium Desktop version 1.7.2` installed.

However, if I try opening any ionic app using Appium Desktop, it hangs at the loading screen and the app never shows up for the ui elements to be interacted with.

[image: Appium Doctor Screen]

The app opens perfectly fine in the emulator though

[image: Emulator]

My `capabilities` are

```
{
  "app": "/Users/zac/Downloads/Demo_ionic.apk",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "8",
  "deviceName": "Pixel 2 XL"
```

}

I have even tried setting the `autoWebview` to `true` but it just opens the browser , which I don't want right now.

Any solutions would be highly appreciated. The `apk` can be found here : https://apkpure.com/constantine-ionic-demo/com.ionicframework.constantine199683

I have tried with multiple ionic .apk files and none of them seem to work on Appium desktop. I am having no problem getting the native apps to open on it, so I think I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have to add this setting for the automation methods :

```
"automationName": "UiAutomator2"
```

It works for me.